# Control "Do Not Disturb" mode of iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7

I want to make an app that activates the "Do Not Disturb" mode for iOS 7. I can't seem to find a way to control it.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there is no public API to access 'Do Not Disturb' functionality.

**Note:** *Please thoroughly search on web before asking a repeated question.*

Comment: @Alectrolytes Please select the answer as right to consider the topic closed for other users which are asking the same question.